# TS2440: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'ProtractorPlugin'

Tags: angular, typescript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Hi i am trying to run a simple protractor test(new to protracotor) but i keep getting this error.Below is my package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "12.12.7",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "husky": "^3.0.9",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.3.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "puppeteer": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.6.4"
  }
```

Answer (score 13):

In my case, the issue was due to a wrong import in a component.

I wrongly wrote this

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'protractor';
```

Instead of writing below import:

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver. I imported element from protractor. Probably through IDE autocomplete.

Answer (score 9):

Seems like the issue with compatibility: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5348

I have fixed it by downgrading typescript to **3.6.2** from 3.7.X

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to downgrade, you can fix the import this way (protractor 5.4.2):

```
import { ElementHelper, ProtractorBrowser } from './browser';
import { ElementArrayFinder, ElementFinder } from './element';
import { ProtractorExpectedConditions } from './expectedConditions';
import { ProtractorBy } from './locators';
import { Ptor } from './ptor';
export { ActionSequence, Browser, Builder, Button, Capabilities, Capability, error, EventEmitter, FileDetector, Key, logging, promise, Session, until, WebDriver, WebElement, WebElementPromise } from 'selenium-webdriver';
export { ElementHelper, ProtractorBrowser } from './browser';
export { Config } from './config';
export { ElementArrayFinder, ElementFinder } from './element';
export { ProtractorExpectedConditions } from './expectedConditions';
export { Locator, ProtractorBy } from './locators';
export { PluginConfig, ProtractorPlugin } from './plugins';
export { Ptor } from './ptor';
export { Runner } from './runner';
export declare let utils: {
    firefox: any;
    http: any;
    remote: any;
};
export declare let Command: any;
export declare let CommandName: any;
export declare let protractor: Ptor;
export declare let browser: ProtractorBrowser;
export declare let $: (search: string) => ElementFinder;
export declare let $$: (search: string) => ElementArrayFinder;
export declare let element: ElementHelper;
export declare let By: ProtractorBy;
export declare let by: ProtractorBy;
export declare let ExpectedConditions: ProtractorExpectedConditions;
```

Basically, there is a dupe import which we need to get rid of. Attached you have the patch:

```
diff -r d5e827235972 yf/src/myapp/node_modules/protractor/built/index.d.ts
--- a/yf/src/myapp/node_modules/protractor/built/index.d.ts Sun Jan 19 20:49:39 2020 +0100
+++ b/yf/src/myapp/node_modules/protractor/built/index.d.ts Sun Jan 19 21:13:41 2020 +0100
@@ -2,7 +2,6 @@
 import { ElementArrayFinder, ElementFinder } from './element';
 import { ProtractorExpectedConditions } from './expectedConditions';
 import { ProtractorBy } from './locators';
-import { PluginConfig, ProtractorPlugin } from './plugins';
 import { Ptor } from './ptor';
 export { ActionSequence, Browser, Builder, Button, Capabilities, Capability, error, EventEmitter, FileDetector, Key, logging, promise, Session, until, WebDriver, WebElement, WebElementPromise } from 'selenium-webdriver';
 export { ElementHelper, ProtractorBrowser } from './browser';
@@ -10,10 +9,9 @@
 export { ElementArrayFinder, ElementFinder } from './element';
 export { ProtractorExpectedConditions } from './expectedConditions';
 export { Locator, ProtractorBy } from './locators';
+export { PluginConfig, ProtractorPlugin } from './plugins';
 export { Ptor } from './ptor';
 export { Runner } from './runner';
-export declare type PluginConfig = PluginConfig;
-export declare type ProtractorPlugin = ProtractorPlugin;
 export declare let utils: {
     firefox: any;
     http: any;
```